# How to use regex for when link contains a specific string?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

How to create a regular expression for when a link contains `wp-content/uploads` path? The problem is somewhere in this `wp-content/uploads` part.

You can see an example here https://regexr.com/3ro5n

```
(<a.*? href=".+?(?:\/wp-content\/uploads)+")><img
```

In the end I am trying to add a class to this links for Lightbox, if those links contain an image

```
function give_linked_images_class($content) {

  $classes = 'fancybox';

  if ( preg_match('/<a.*?><img/', $content) ) {
    $content = preg_replace('/(<a.*? href=".+?(?:\/wp-content\/uploads)+")><img/', '$1 class="' . $classes . '" ><img', $content);
  }
  return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content','give_linked_images_class');
```

Comment: So why exactly wouldn't this work? [`<a.*wp-content\/uploads.*<\/a`](https://regex101.com/r/qBlF62/14/)

Comment: In your link you're missing one small detail. Instead of `(<a.*? href=".+?(?:\/wp-content\/uploads)+")><img` you need to use this `(<a.*? href=".+?(?:\/wp-content\/uploads)+.*")><img` Your pattern will only match if the href link ends with content/uploads

Comment: Please check marked question. You shouldn't use RegEx to parse HTML.